# Exercicio com pilha - String com lixo

Tags: c, string, stack

> Escreva um algoritmo, usando uma Pilha, que inverte as letras de cada palavra de um texto terminado por ponto (.) preservando a ordem
>   das palavras. Por
>   exemplo, dado o texto: ESTE EXERCICIO E MUITO FACIL. A saıda deve ser: ETSE OICICREXE E OTIUM LICAF

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

char Pop(char *pilha, int *topo);
void Push(char valor, char *pilha, int *topo);

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");

    char pilha[100], aux, saida[100];
    int topo = -1, i = 0;

    do {
        aux = getche();

        if (aux != ' ' && aux != '.') {
            Push(aux, pilha, &topo);
        } else {
            while (topo > -1)  {
                saida[i++] = Pop(pilha, &topo);
            }
        saida[i++] = ' ';
        }
        if (aux == ' ') aux = '-';

    } while (aux != '.');

    saida[strlen(saida) -1] = '\0';

    printf("\n%s\n", saida);

    return 0;
}

char Pop(char *pilha, int *topo) {
        if (*topo == -1)
            printf("Pilha vazia!\n");
        else {
            *topo -= 1;
            return pilha[*topo +1];
        }
}

void Push(char valor, char *pilha, int *topo) {
        if (*topo == 100)
            printf("Pilha cheia!\n");
        else {
            *topo += 1;
            pilha[*topo] = valor;
        }
}
```

Este código está funcionando. Porém, dependendo da frase, ele imprime lixo junto. Alguem consegue me indicar onde está o problema? obrigada!
já tentei ler normal e ir passando pra pilha utilizando um for.. mas não funcionou..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu código tem 2 problemas sendo um mais grave que outro.

- Usar `strlen` numa string sem terminador:

  ```
  saida[strlen(saida) -1] = '\0';
  ```

  Este é o problema mais grave que tem no código e que faz com que apanhe lixo na memoria. Acontece que a string não tem terminador pois você está precisamente a tentar colocar ele, mas está a calcular o fim da string com `strlen`.

  Pois bem, **`strlen` só funciona quando a string tem terminador, e quando não tem representa comportamento indefinido**.

  Corrigir esta parte é facil pois o seu `i` foi aumentando à medida que foi colocando carateres na `saida` e por isso o seu valor final é o tamanho da string. Logo deve colocar o terminador também com base no `i`:

  ```
  saida[i] = '\0';
  ```
- Não definir retornos em todas os caminhos de execução, o que acontece na função `Pop`:

  ```
  char Pop(char *pilha, int *topo) {
      if (*topo == -1)
          printf("Pilha vazia!\n");  // <-- se o código vier por aqui não tem retorno
      else {   
          *topo -= 1;
          return pilha[*topo +1];
      }
  }
  ```

  Repare que se o apontado por `topo` for `-1` o código entra no `if` mas depois não tem nenhum retorno associado e a função espera que seja retornado um `char`, que está a utilizar em:

  ```
  saida[i++] = Pop(pilha, &topo);
  ```

  Este erro é menos grave pois o valor só é consumido quando o `topo` é diferente de `-1` devido à condição que está no `while`, mas é algo que deve evitar fazer, e que mais à frente pode resultar num erro se não tiver atenção.

  **Todas as funções que retornam algo devem definir um valor de retorno para todos os caminhos possíveis de execução.**

Nota: Apenas como uma pequena dica em relação à nomenclatura, os nomes das funções regra geral começam com letra pequena e por isso as duas funções que tem deviam se chamar `pop` e `push`